# can't find libpython3.8.a while install uwsgi

Tags: python3, uwsgi

when I run the command to install uwsgi,

```
pip install uwsgi
```

I got such error:

```
gcc: error: /home/shawn/anaconda3/envs/i2dl/lib/python3.8/config-3.8-x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.a: No such file or directory
*** error linking uWSGI ***
```

even though I have used "apt install libpython3.8" and "python3.8-dev" also has a gcc. I have no idea why I don't have libpython3.8.a.

Comment: Were you able to solve this?